# Redis: Free used_memory_rss without restarting redis

Tags: memory-management, redis, defragmentation

Over time the used_memory_rss keeps increasing. I understand the reason behind it getting filled (its how memory allocators work). However I need a solution to free it without restarting redis.

Is there any way to do the same?

Comment: Have you checked the docs already?

Comment: Yes there is not mention of how to clear the used_memory_rss space in the docs.

Answer (score 1):

in redis 4.0 there is a new command

```
MEMORY PURGE
```

that will defragment memory and release it to the OS.

also see

```
MEMORY HELP
```

Answer (score 0):

You may reference to this issue [compact memory use  online](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/redis-db/fAlvkK2keBw)

Comment: The post says to create a slave which replicates all the data and then promote that slave as master. We have been doing this only as of now. But I was looking for an alternative solution to simply defragment the current redis instance so that used_memory_rss reduces.